# Custom tomcat context.xml for Spring App

Tags: spring, tomcat

I have a Spring App, and I would like change the session cookie path. I know this can be done in the server's context.xml file, but I don't have permission to edit that file on my server. Is there another way to do this, maybe by adding another context.xml file somewhere?

Btw, I added a context.xml file to my project's META-INF folder, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundle your `context.xml` with your war file.